# customization of ng serve command angular

Tags: angular, bash, git

I need to customize `ng serve` command to run angular application.

Requirement - I need to run some bash script commands before every `ng serve`, for example If I run command `ng serve`, I would need to run commands like this

`node abc.js && ng serve`

Not sure if this is possible or not, If so please help.

PS: I don't want to use npm start instead, I have tried to changes script in package.json file but won't work this way.

PPS: Or Is there any way to run same command before any git command? say I run command `git add .` it should internally run `node abc.js && git add .`

Comment: git hook will do he job ‍♂️ 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**npm scripts**

you can use npm package.json script the have already made so shorctcut like here

```
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
```

and the can be run like this `npm start`  or `npm build` but you can create you own script for example

```
"prod": "ng build --prod",
```

the custome script run like this `npm run prod`

**git hooks**

like pre-commit , every Git repository has a .git/hooks folder with a script for each hook you can bind to. You're free to change or update these scripts as necessary, and Git will execute them when those events occur.

in the `.git/hooks` create a file called `pre-commit` later update the file like this

```
node abs 

git add .
```

*run ng build before and commit*

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('running fast build test .....');

require('child_process').exec(
  'ng build',
  function (error, stdout) {
    console.log(stdout && 'stdout: ' + stdout);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(error);
      process.abort(0);
    }
  }
);
```

these command above will run before each commit ,give it a try

[githooks](https://githooks.com/)

Comment: I already tried changing npm script you suggested, but no luck.
Yes sure, I'll give it a try github hooks and update you.

Comment: file name should be only `pre-commit` without any extension? as I can see there are already few file having extension as `.sample`

Comment: tried, but not working. most probably I wrote wrong code, can you post full source code for the `pre-commit` file

Comment: Git hooks won't solve his first issue which is using `ng serve` to run `node abc.js && ng serve`

Comment: @Dino true, won't solve my first issue, but yes answer is useful somewhere. I'll try to customize suggestion as per my requirements. Thanks #malbarmawi

Comment: if run git from pre-commit will not work untill the second commit so I found you can use -a flag `git commit -a -m "message " `  this will solve the first issue add the files @PardeepJain

Comment: thank you, I solved by changing the pre-commit file with line `exec node filepath` and working fine.

Comment: I have update my answer with an example of running ng build before any commit in case the build failed the commit will fail 

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` of Angular project, change to following and run `npm start` instead of `ng serve`

```
 "scripts": { ...   
   "start": "node abc.js && ng serve,
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Quote --> ```PS: I don't want to use npm start instead```

Comment: @chaitanya Please read my question correctly, I already said I dont want to use npm start instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom `npm` command in `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "custom": "node abc.js && ng serve"
   }
```

And then you have to execute `npm run custom`. It will first execute `node abc.js` and then `ng serve`.

Remember to use `npm run <command-name>` instead of `npm <command-name>`.

If you use `run`, it will look for your local (project) npm. Without run it will look for the global one (installed globally on your machine), and your custom command will not run (As it's not declared globally).

Comment: @Paradeep Jain You've only mentioned the npm start. Be more specific next time

Comment: it's self understood with one example, anyways clearly mentiond `...before every ng serve`

Comment: Exactly, and this approach DOES run command before every ng serve. I understand your point now, I'm just saying that you didn't express correctly when asking a question.